# Geocoding Human Development Index (HDI) data

Tags: qgis, csv, geocoding

I am using QGIS for a class and I am trying to make a world map based on [Human Development Index (HDI)](http://hdr.undp.org/en/content/human-development-index-hdi) data I got from the UN website. However, the data is in CSV and without latitude and longitude.

I already have a map of political boundaries of the world, but how would I orient the data so that it matches up with the political boundaries?

Also, the data I have is for multiple years and I would like to be able to show or not show a year's data by clicking a button if possible.

If there is HDI data available that includes latitude and longitude, I would be open to using that as long as it is recent.

Comment: First, what is HDI? What columns *does* your data contain? If this data is tabular by country name then you could consider joining to an administrative boundary dataset - be sure to validate your names though, country names can change and that would lead to an unjoined row.

Comment: HDI is Human Development Index. It contains 26 columns of data total spread out over 52 colums, plus an extra column that is used for the ranking of HDI. In column A it lists the ranking of countries by their HDI. in Column 2 it lists the Countries Alphabetically. In the following colums it lists the HDI by year between 1990 and 2015.

Comment: You could use an attribute join by country name to get the aspatial data spatial. The problem you're going to encounter is, as there are multiple rows between 1990 and 2015 there is no way to tell which row will be joined, it would be best to filter the table by each target year and join. Be *very* sure that the country names exactly match or you will get an unjoined row.

Comment: @Qiangong2 it would be better if you share a sample table.

Comment: @OverArch you can download the csv directly from the UN's website, but here is a smaller example: https://www.megaupload.us/1OK3/examplecsv.csv

Comment: @Qiangong2 I am not able to access the link. Better to paste sample data here itself or a screenshot.